# Force SSL except on the homepage index.php using .htccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

I want to force every page on my website to use SSL (https) except the homepage index.php using .htccess

Answer (score 1):

In the htaccess file in your document root, add these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index.php)?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```